# Access 2013 Frontend fails to load - backend linking Issue

Tags: ms-access-2013

I splitted the database, and then did some changes directly into backend. and then i tried to open front end, it failed to open and just asking for new/other files to open. what am i missing here ?

I gave up and opened my another backup access file and splitted it in frontend-backend. let say frontend name :DBstore7_fe and backend name:Dbstore7_be. link is ok and i can update data from front end. but i have to keep my old version of backend(Dbstore6_be) in the same folder. if i remove this old backend version, my frontend fails to open.

i tried another thing, i imported back all the tables to the front end, i.e - no more backend/linking. but still it is looking for Dbstore6_be. if this one there ....my database loads otherwise prompting for blank version.

Answer (score 0):

You must run the "External Data", "Manage Linked Tables" wizard whenever you move or modify the backend file.